# How do I enable a disabled select option?

Tags: javascript, php, attributes, null, onchange

I have a drop down being generated by JavaScript. Basically when a selection is made this dropdown changes with values (on the onchange event), if the value returned is a null or blank then it should be disabled, which works fine but when the selection is changed and values are reloaded then even the values that are not blank are disabled?

Here is the code, all I am saying in this simple loop is: if the value is not blank then keep the value enabled else if it is a blank then disable those values:

```
   echo "\t\tfor(index=1; index < $maxfield1rows; index++)\n";
       echo "\t\t{\n";
       echo "\t\tif(document.pickDivision.field1.options[index].value !='')\n";
           echo "\t\t{\n";
           echo "\t\tdocument.pickDivision.field1.options[index].enabled=true\n"; 
           echo "\t\t}\n\n";
           echo "\t\telse\n";
              echo "\t\t{\n";
              echo "\t\t(document.pickDivision.field1.options[index].disabled=true)\n"; 
       echo "\t\t}\n\n";      
    echo "\t\t}\n\n";
```

Please help if you can.

Comment: you could skip ALL of those repeated echoes by just dropping out of PHP mode, or at least using a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc)...

Comment: Dynamic JS  (generated with PHP) is a really nasty pattern, really hard to follow, really hard to reuse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `disabled = false`;

```
echo "\t\tfor(index=1; index < $maxfield1rows; index++)\n";
       echo "\t\t{\n";
       echo "\t\tif(document.pickDivision.field1.options[index].value !='')\n";
           echo "\t\t{\n";
           echo "\t\tdocument.pickDivision.field1.options[index].disabled=false\n"; 
           echo "\t\t}\n\n";
           echo "\t\telse\n";
              echo "\t\t{\n";
              echo "\t\t(document.pickDivision.field1.options[index].disabled=true)\n"; 
       echo "\t\t}\n\n";      
    echo "\t\t}\n\n";
```

Comment: sorry one other question, after disabling these blank lines, is there a way I can remove them?  I mean the blank lines still show, they are disabled so you can't select them, but is there a way to make them not show?